# syntax error in update statement using Access 2010

Tags: c#, sql

I keep getting an error that there is a syntax error in my update statement. Any ideas on how to resolve this? I have used a very similar code in another program and it worked fine so I am stumped. I have tried with the '' and without in the SQL statement without a difference in the result.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
{
   try
   {
      string cmdstring = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET Location = '@location', Position = '@position' WHERE TellerNum = '@teller'";
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
      {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", comboBox18.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", comboBox19.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", comboBox17.Text);
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
      }
      string inststring = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (Comments) VALUES (@comments) WHERE TellerNum = @teller";
      using (OleDbCommand insert = new OleDbCommand(inststring, con))
      {
         insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", textBox8.Text);
         insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", comboBox17.Text);
         con.Open();
         insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
      }
      MessageBox.Show("Submitted Successfully");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Um, I don't think INSERT statement supports WHERE clause. What are u trying to achieve?

Comment: Oh that is good to know. I want the comments to be attached to a specific TellerNum. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to update existing comment in EMPLOYEE table or every time add new one?

Comment: "Attached"?  So linked by an ID of some sort?  Doesn't that mean setting an additional field in the INSERT statement to be `teller` value?

Comment: I want to be able to update the employee location and position but also be able to add a comment without replacing previous comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explainedi in comments, the Syntax error is due to the presence of the WHERE clause in an INSERT INTO statement, but if you want to update an existing employee record with comments, location and position you could do with just one command. Notice also that you don't put the parameter placeholders between single quotes. If you do that, you transform the placeholders in literal values hiding the parameter value

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring))
{
   try
   {
      string cmdstring = @"UPDATE EMPLOYEE 
                           SET Location = @location, 
                           Comments = @Comments,
                           [Position] = @position 
                           WHERE TellerNum = @teller";
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdstring, con))
      {
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", comboBox18.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comments", textBox8.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@position", comboBox19.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@teller", comboBox17.Text);
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed due to " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

if you want to append a new comment to the previous comments, then your query should be (always an update query) like this

```
string cmdstring = @"UPDATE EMPLOYEE 
                     SET Location = @location, 
                     Comments = Comments + @Comments,
                     [Position] = @position 
                     WHERE TellerNum = @teller";
```

There is also the problem arising from the use of a reserved keyword. Using reserved keyword is well known to cause a syntax error. In your case POSITION is a [reserved keyword in MS-Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) and thus, you need to enclose it in square brakets. (However it will be preferable to change that name to something different to avoid to repeat the same error in future)

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the updating the comments while keeping old ones. However, it is continuing to give me the same update syntax error. It may help to know that my Access DB is set up as follows:   TellerNum = AutoNumber,  Position = Text,   Location = Text,  Comments = Text.

Comment: Hey FYI, I put brackets around each of the column names and it fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: True, POSITION is a reserved keyword in MS-Access, I will add this to the answer